# Saving a previous authentication in Spring

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, microservices, spring-security-oauth2, netflix-zuul

As an authentication, the application (Service-X) uses a third-party internal service (Service-Y), in which all the information about the employees is stored. All internal services of the company use SSO.

How to implement the ability to log in to Service-X if Service-Y is unavailable? (If I have already been authenticated in Service-X before this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [remember-me](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/remember-me.html) feature that comes with Spring Security might be what you're looking for.

However, there are still quite a few limitations to this. If your cookies are wiped upon closing the browser, which is quite common in a lot of big companies, this won't work. Other than by the session cookie, you can't *safely* remember the user. You absolutely require `Service-Y` to be available to identify the user if his cookies have been cleared or have expired.

The main selling point of OAuth2 is that you sign in using `Service-Y` without `Service-X` knowing your username/password *(unless the username is transmitted through the scope)*, so while you could ask the user to provide a password on the first time he signs in `Service-X` using `Service-Y` in case `Service-Y` goes down, which would *potentially* patch your issue, I really **do not recommend it** because it somewhat defeats the purpose of OAuth2.

Now, if you do take that suggestion despite me not recommending it, you should make sure that `Service-X` **checks** that `Service-Y` is down before allowing the user to sign in using the password he provided for `Service-X`.

Best case scenario, if your browser cookies aren't cleaned, go for the remember-me feature. I suggest you read the following: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth2-remember-me